# Equivalence of the Parallel Postulate and Existence of Rectangles.

Tags: geometry

How can I prove that these statements are equivalent?

Comment: A proof is given on page 4 of www.msu.edu/~ottensam/NonEuclid.doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"A proof is given on page 4 of www.msu.edu/~ottensam/NonEuclid.doc " - Gerry Myerson, in comments.